# JPA ManyToOne addition parameters

Tags: java, jpa, jboss

I have two table entity:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "TEST_PARENT")
public class Parent{
    @Id
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_CONTRACT_ID")
    Long parentContractId;

    //getters and setters    
}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_CHILD")
public class Child{
    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_CONTRACT_ID")
    Parent parent;
}
```

Is there any way to get parent with maximum ID (or to make custom select for get parent) for this table data:

```
**TEST_PARENT**
ID PARENT_CONTRACT_ID
1  100
2  100 
3  200

**TEST_CHILD**
ID PARENT_ID
1  100
```

Query select: "from Child t where t.id = 1";

Query result Child class:

{Id = 1

Parent - **ID = 2**, PARENT_CONTRACT_ID = 100 
}

Comment: What do you mean by....."Is there any way to get parent with maximum ID.. ?" ...... Parent with most child ??

Comment: I want to select parent like this:
"select max(t.ID) from TEST_PARENT t" 
not like this: 
"select * from TEST_PARENT t where t.id = 1"

Answer (score 0):

The query will be:

```
SELECT max(c.id) FROM Child c
```

And you can use this from your `EntityManager` like this way:

```
Long max = em.createQuery("SELECT max(c.id) FROM Child c", Long.class).getSingleResult();
```